# Why is LoadImage loading my 16x16 icon as 32x32?

Tags: c++, mfc

Let me start by saying that I'm new to C++ and MFC.

The past few days I've been trying to display a 16x16 icon in my client area and even though it displays the right image, the icon is always being scaled to 32x32 and looks distorted.
I've been searching and tried different ways of LoadIcon, LoadImage but nothing seems to work.

Here is a sample of LoadImage:

```
m_icon1 = (HICON)::LoadImage(AfxGetApp()->m_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);
int xIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMSIZE);
int yIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMSIZE);
CRect rect;
GetClientRect(&rect);
int xx = (rect.Width() - xIcon  + 1) / 2;
int yy = (rect.Height() - yIcon  + 1) / 2;
dc.DrawIcon(xx, yy, m_icon1 );
```

IconInfo:

[image: IconInfo]

Here is the window, the left icon is 32x32 and the right is the 16x16, as you can see they have the same size. I put a different color to each size just to be sure.

[image: Icon comparison]

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadimagea) under the `LR_SHARED` section: *This function finds the first image in the cache with the requested resource name, regardless of the size requested.*

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica Thank you, I have tried with 0 or even the LR_VGACOLOR and it does the same thing.

Comment: Can you call for GetIconInfo after the call and attach the output to the question? The size you be there.

Comment: Can you show us the code that actually draws/displays the loaded icon? Maybe it's there that the 'stretching' is being done - you have said that it looks 'distorted'.

Comment: From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-drawicon): DrawIcon draws the icon or cursor using the width and height specified by the system metric values for icons; for more information, see GetSystemMetrics.

Comment: You have to use `DrawIconEx` instead. This is not available as MFC method, so you have to call `::DrawIconEx(dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0, 0, hicon, ...)`